# leaflet.js (using geojson data) country labels incorrect

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using leaflet.js (with geojson) to display a map. [Removing some of the code code to make it more concise].

```
   $.getJSON('./api/map/data', function(data){
        let minZoom = 2.25
        let defaultZoom = 2.25
        let map = L.map('map', {
            minZoom: minZoom,
            zoomSnap: 0.1
        }).setView([43, 0], defaultZoom);

        let onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
            var label = L.marker(layer.getBounds().getCenter(), {
                icon: L.divIcon({
                    className: 'countryLabel',
                    html: feature.properties.name,
                    iconSize: [0, 0]
                })
            }).addTo(map);
        };

        L.geoJson(data, {
            clickable: false,
            style: {},
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        }).addTo(map);
```

I used [this website](https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/) to download vector maps. Some of the labels are clearly incorrect (and some of them are almost correct). On inspection it seems like some of the lat/longs are not correctly set (or so it seems). Any feedback on how i could make this show up correctly? It would be great if i could come up with labels such that they fit the country borders (meaning maybe add country code wherever necessary).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is connected with your label options. At this moment, your icon position pointing to left top corner of your label and you need to set offset to move label to the center of coordinates. Property that might help you is `iconAnchor` [(see leaflet docs)](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#icon-iconanchor)